# Defining explicit conversion - possible GCC bug

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to define a simple explicit conversion in C++11, separately from the header file, using GCC 4.8.5 (CentOS 7's default):

foo.h:

```
#ifndef foo_h_
#define foo_h_

typedef struct {
    int x;
    explicit operator int() const;
} A;

#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

A::operator int() const
{
    return this->x;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(int,char**)
{
    A a{1};
    int b = (int)a - 1;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.8.5 inexplicably fails to link this code:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp main.cpp
/tmp/cc5osctA.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `A::operator int() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if I use any version of GCC >= 5 (e.g. GCC 5.3.1 from RHEL's devtoolset-4 software collection), it works, as I'd expect it to:

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-4 "g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp main.cpp"
### (no linker errors, b == 0 when running)
```

---

Is this a bug in GCC 4.8.5's C++11 support? Or is my code malformed?

Comment: Why `typedef struct {} A;`? that's more C than C++.

Comment: GCC 4.x.x is beyond obsolete.

Comment: Note that `_foo_h_` is a reserved identifier.

Comment: Formally, the header file has undefined behaviour, due to use of a reserved identifier as an include guard.   Remove the leading `_`.     As to the actual problem, try reversing the order the `.cpp` files are listed on the command line.   Some older toolchains and their linkers (and gcc4 is OLD) were sensitive to such things, in resolving symbols used between compilation units.

Comment: @peter ah, I wasn't aware that that was a reserved identifier. To be fair, this is just a MCVE I threw together in 5 minutes, so I didn't think twice about the `#include` guards. Anyways -- @neil I realize GCC 4 is old, but the fact remains that it's the default on RHEL and CentOS 7 and is still supported by RedHat. I'm just academically curious if my code is allowed, much more so than wanting to use this old compiler for production builds.

Comment: @peter reversing the order of the `.cpp` files didn't fix the linker error, nor did changing the reserved identifier `#include` guard. I'm guessing GCC 4 just didn't correctly implement the linking for `explicit` conversion functions correctly

Comment: Having some deja-vu, that this was asked in the last week, or so, and that this was a known bug in this ancient version of gcc. Can't find the dupe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is that very question. It probably popped up for you again because I edited the code snippet to remove the leading underscore on my `#include` macro. I'm going to try to find in the standard where it might explicitly say that my code is allowed.